# Convert dash separated string to datatime2 sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, casting

I saved date and time in my data base as file names. Each file name is a dash separated string, for example `2017-12-29-23-23-59-999.BMP`(you can assume that the format is yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-000.BMP).  How can I cast this string to datetime2 in `Microsoft SQL server 2014`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method, assuming 999 is fractional seconds:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(100) = '2017-12-29-23-23-59-999.BMP';

SELECT CAST(
      SUBSTRING(@FileName, 1, 10) 
    + 'T' 
    + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@FileName, 12, 8), '-', ':') 
    + '.' 
    + SUBSTRING(@FileName, 21, 3)
    AS datetime2);
```